# Python, how to use item inputed in a list and use them to be assigned another value? is it possible

Tags: python, list, object

I'm writing a program to take a number of players as input from the user and add that many names to a list. Now I want to take the names that are added to the list and use them in a scoring system for each of the players in the `player_list`.

I want to use each name to say *this player* has *this many* points. So I believe I want to use the names in the list as each an object and assign each a score.

My question is, can I do this with items in a list? 
My code right now that works to create the list is as follows.

```
# total_list is to be used in the next part of my code
total_list = []
players_list = []

max_players = int(input(" how many players tonight? : "))

while len(players_list) < max_players:
    players = input("First player name? : ")
    players_list.append(players)
    print("players so far : ")
    print(players_list)
    if len(players_list) == max_players:
        print("players are: ")
        print(players_list)
```

The way my code is right now, can I use the name input to the list as an object and assign a variable called `score`?

I think it would look like something like this:

```
players_list[0](score)
```

but I know that would not be the way to write it, if it is indeed possible. Please let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Try a key-value pair structure like a [dictionary](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python).

Comment: You can use a dictionary with names as the keys and the score object as the value if you are sure that all the players have a unique name. Otherwise you use a unique property for each player like their serial number and use this serial number as the key in this dictionary.

Comment: that is literally what I am looking for, would a dictionary  take user input for the key and value? I can change the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a perfect application for a new Player class:

```
class  Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    def __repr__(self, name):
        return self.name
```

Then, instead of `players_list.append(players)`, you would do `players_list.append(Player(players))` (also IMHO you should use something like *name* instead of *players* just so it's more clear what that actually is).

Then, all the players in your list will have an associated score that you can access like `players_list[0].score`.

Hope this helps, good luck learning.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking questions, but what does def __init__ and def __repr__ mean and does "self" always have to be in the "()"?

Comment: and yes I will google as well and thank you! I was really happy to finally create a lil snippet that worked lol

Comment: `__init__` and `__repr__` are methods that define how instances of the class are initialized and represented when printed, respectively. Here's some reading about [magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/). And the reason that `self` is a parameter in class methods is that when you call them using `<instance>.<method>()`, the instance gets passed in as the first argument -- so you can access instance variables and other methods. 500 characters isn't really enough to explain all the nuances there but feel free to ask more questions in chat.

Comment: Thank you!! I am reading your link right now, and I have no clue how to chat on here bah.

Comment: Here's a link to a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173174/beginners-python).

Comment: Dang it need 8 more reputation before I can chat on there. I am changing around my code right now and I think I am doing it right, If I have an error, you bet I am going to post it on here haha

Comment: Hold on back to the first post you had on here, would I keep my players_list or do I change that to Class Players?

Comment: Looks like you have enough rep to use the chat room now

Comment: I am getting this error now __Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lindsey\Documents\testscore.py", line 14, in <module>
    print (players_list)
TypeError: __repr__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'__

Comment: it says I need 20 rep

Comment: Try refreshing, you have 22

Comment: I tried, it did refresh to show I have 22 but on the link, even refreshing on there, it is still saying I need 20, could the link be old?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173178/discussion-between-lindsey-betancourt-and-moxieball).

Answer (score 0):

Objects are really the way to go but if you don't want to do OOP then you can use a dictionary:

```
players = {}

players['geddy'] ={}
players['alex'] = {}
players['neil'] = {}

players['geddy']['score']=1;
players['alex']['score']=2;
players['neil']['score']=3;


print players
```

output:

```
{'alex': {'score': 2}, 'neil': {'score': 3}, 'geddy': {'score': 1}}
```

An example OOP solution:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name="", points=0):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points

    def identify(self):
        print "my name is ", self.name, "and I have ", self.points, "points"

    def scored(self):
        self.points += 1;

class Players:

    def __init__(self):
        self.players = []

    def addPlayer(self, name):
        self.players.append(Player(name))

    def getPlayer(self, name):
        for player in self.players:
            if player.name == name:
                return player

    def winner(self):
        score, player = max([ (player.points, player) for player in self.players ])
        return player

players = Players()

players.addPlayer('Geddy');
players.addPlayer('Alex');
players.addPlayer('Neil');

players.getPlayer('Geddy').scored();
players.getPlayer('Geddy').scored();
players.getPlayer('Geddy').scored();

players.getPlayer('Alex').scored();
players.getPlayer('Alex').scored();

players.getPlayer('Neil').scored();

for p in players.players:
    p.identify();

print "The winner is ", players.winner().name
```

Output:

```
my name is  Geddy and I have  3 points
my name is  Alex and I have  2 points
my name is  Neil and I have  1 points
The winner is  Geddy
```

Have fun

Comment: I am definitely trying to go OOP which I believe would be to go with class' but using a dictionary seems easier, but I don't want easy I want to learn OOP, o my so many different ways!!!

Comment: Then go OOP.  A dictionary really isn't what you want.  You probably want a player object that contains his name, score, and player number.

Comment: That's exactly what I want honestly. I don't have much experience with class' but I would love to have the output say "player 1 name score" so time for me to learn more about classes which oddly wasn't in any of the basics part of the books I been reading. I figured it should be a basic thing to learn though right?

Comment: Well, I don't know what the book is trying to teach you right now.  I would suspect that if the book hasn't covered classes by now then it's trying to teach you about basic Python constructs like strings, lists, sets, and dictionaries.  If they aren't talking about OOP then don't put the cart before the horse.

Comment: In other words, if the book isn't trying to teach you about classes then stick to the book and don't skip ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Uses dictionaries and F-Strings for a cleaner look. Technically MoxieBall's Class answer is most Pythonic but could be tricky if unfamiliar with classes.

```
players_dict = {}
max_players = int(input(" how many players tonight? : " ))
for num, x in enumerate(range(max_players)):
    player = input(f"Player {num+1} name? : ")
    players_dict[player] = {'score':0}
    print(f"players so far : {list(players_dict)} ")

print (f"players are: {list(players_dict)}")
```

Then later to update scores you simply do `player_dict['name']['score'] = 3`

Comment: It is tricky, class' that is , I like how you redid this so simple and short, may I ask what the "f" in all the print is?

Comment: It's a relatively new feature in Python called F-Strings. You put an f before a string and it makes it an f-string. They're pretty useful for inserting values into the middle of strings. Here's a [good intro guide](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/). There are other methods like .format() and % but F-strings is now the fastest and I think cleanest approach.

Comment: I also just realised I made an edit that made the example non-functional. It's now fixed (put the enumerate back in).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to initiate a Dictionary, like this-

```
total_list = {}
max_players = int(input(" how many players tonight? : "))

for _ in range(max_players):
    player=input("Name of the player ")
    total_list[player]=input("Score? ")

print(total_list['b'])
```

hope this is what you were looking for.